# How to display all microposts from specific user id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been unable to display microposts that are strictly from admin user in my users' feed.

I have an if statement that renders all microposts from users to the admin user, and would like users to only see microposts coming from the admin user in my else statement.

```
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>
<% if logged_in? %>
<div class="col-sm-6 center-block float_none">
<div class="post_">
  <section class="user_info">
    <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
  </section> 

  <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>

  <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
</div>

<% if current_user.admin? %>
  <h1 class="white_">Our upcoming trips..</h1>
    <ul class="list-group feed_ white_">
      <%= render Micropost.all %>
    </ul>

<% else %>

<h1 class="white_">Our upcoming trips..</h1>
  <ul class="list-group feed_ white_">
    <%= render ?  %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

</div>
```

My question is how do you extract all microposts from a single user, admin in this case, and render them in the view?

Comment: Add a boolean column public in microposts table. Whenever a post is created by admin make this attribute true, else false. Then by using scopes, In Micropost model scope :by_admin, -> { where(public: true) }. Now Micropost.by_admin.all gives you the result.

Comment: Thanks Vamsi, that was the answer to my question !